# How do we assure that an ansible registered variable has a particular attribute

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements, undefined, attributeerror

I have a playbook that has the below SQL query:

```
  - name: "Search for Front"
    command: >
      mysql --user="{{ DBUSER }}" --password="{{ DBPASS }}" deployment
      --host=localhost --batch --skip-column-names
      --execute="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num LIKE '{{ Number }}'"
    register: result_front
    when: Layer == 'Front'

  - name: "Search for Back"
    command: >
      mysql --user="{{ DBUSER }}" --password="{{ DBPASS }}" deployment
      --host=localhost --batch --skip-column-names
      --execute="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE num LIKE '{{ Number }}'"
    register: result_back
    when: Layer == 'Back'
```

I trigger this playbook as below:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e "Layer=Front" -e "Number=1234" -e "DBUSER=root" -e "DBPASS=password"
```

Note that at a time only one of the two sql query will execute depending on the parameter "Layer" passed.

I wish to set_fact "reqnum" to string "Deploy" if any of the above two SQL queries returns records found.

Below is what i did:

```
   - set_fact:
       reqnum: "Deploy"
     when: result_back.stdout_lines | default([]) | length != ""  and result_back.skipped == False

   - set_fact:
       reqnum: "Deploy"
     when: result_front.stdout_lines |  default([]) | length != ""  and result_front.skipped == False
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result_back.stdout_lines == \"\"  and result_back.skipped == False' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result_back.stdout_lines == \"\"  and result_back.skipped == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/deploy.yml': line 149, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - set_fact:\n     ^ here\n"}
```

What is the correct way to to check such conditions where one variable gets skipped while the other gets a failure or success as a result ?

Comment: If the task is skipped, the `stdout_lines` property does not exist. So testing for skip is enough in your scenario. Else you need to default the value with something like: `my_register.stdout_lines | default([]) | length == 0`. Note that `stdout_lines` will never be equal to an empty string since it is a list.

Comment: I updated my original post taking in account your suggestion but now i get the error 'dict object' has no attribute 'skipped'

Comment: `bla.skipped == True` => `bla is skipped`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Comment: This is even a better doc link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#task-results

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way to to check such conditions where one variable gets skipped while the other gets a failure or success as a result ?

It is to change the order of the `when:` so it evaluates the `is skipped` check first, and then won't try to blow up on the variable reference; for example:

```
- command: date
  register: alpha
  when: doit == 'alpha'

- command: uptime
  register: beta
  when: doit == 'beta'

- set_fact:
    reqnum: Deploy Alpha
  when: alpha is not skipped and (alpha.stdout_lines|length) > 0

- set_fact:
    reqnum: Deploy Beta
  when: beta is not skipped and (beta.stdout_lines|length) > 0

- debug: var=reqnum
```

All of that is exactly what @Zeitounator was trying to tell you, but just packaged into one working example